# do_shortcode not running ajaxlaodmore shortcode

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am using ajaxloadmore plugin. it works perfect from the code below inside template.

but when I call above code from the ajax call it returns empty divs with no records.
can someone let me know why it dosen't work from ajax call.

Comment: <?php  echo do_shortcode( ' [ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="3"  ] ' );?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax load more plugin uses ajax to load posts. Why are you not using its inbuilt functionality? You cannot use ajax inside PHP code for another ajax.

If you use this shortcode in ajax action, I don't think it will load it's JS files. If you could share some more details about what you are trying to achieve here, I might be able to help.

Also, if it does work somehow, you also need to manage the offset parameters or you will end up loading the same post again and again.

**Edit 1-**

You can reload the page when the user selects a category and by default, you can use all categories.

Try below code:-

```
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'category' ] ) && $_GET[ 'category' ] !== '' ) {

    $cat = esc_html( $_GET[ 'category' ] );

 } else {
    $cat = "in-the-news,leadership,tips-tricks,trends";
 }

 echo do_shortcode( '[ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="6" category="' . $cat . '" ]' );
```

Comment: on home page 
 <div id="know_more_about"> 
 <?php  echo do_shortcode( ' [ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" ] ' );?>
         </div>

Comment: on home I also have this code
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function(){         
            jQuery('#category_id_select').change(function(e) { 
                var cat_id = jQuery(this).val();    
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : ajax_sib_front_object.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'want2know_post',
                cat_id : cat_id
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                       jQuery('#know_more_about').html(response);
             }
        });
    });
    });
</script>

Comment: if ( !function_exists( 'want2know' ) ) {            
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_want2know_post', 'want2know' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_want2know_post', 'want2know' );
function want2know(){
                
$cat_id = absint($_POST['cat_id']) ;
 if($cat_id>0)
 echo  do_shortcode( ' [ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" category__and="'.$cat_id.'"] ' ) ;
 else 
 echo do_shortcode( ' [ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" ] ' );    die();
            }
        }

Comment: the scenario is simple on home page all posts from all categories are being shown
and there is select box having categories
I want if I select a category from that select box ajaxloader sould show posts from that category

Comment: You should use custom wp query in ajax to show posts from a particular category. If you still want to use ajax load more, then you should reload the homepage with the cat id as query string and set query string as the cat id in the shortcode

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode( ' [ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" ] ' );?> why this code is not returning data if i call it from ajax request

Comment: if ( isset( $_GET[ 'category' ] ) && $_GET[ 'category' ] !== '' ) {
  $cat = esc_html( $_GET[ 'category' ] );
} else {
  $cat = "in-the-news,leadership,tips-tricks,trends";
 }
                        
 echo do_shortcode( '[ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="6" category="' . $cat . '" ]' );

Comment: Ok i try to reload home page with selected category

Comment: As I already mentioned, it will not work in ajax. use the code I shared above using query string

Comment: great, I will update my answer and share the code there.

Comment: Can't I pass category id once ajaxlodemore has been rendered because What I need it to do it using ajax and not by reloading page?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can try some custom here to do this if you are creating some filters or even use some plugin. Here's a [link](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html) for custom code.